# After upgrade, Matrix won't save image references

Tags: matrix, bug

Just upgraded to Matrix 2.5.9 on an EE 2.5.3 site, and I'm experiencing a problem with images columns in Matrix rows:

- I create a new entry
- I add a Matrix row with text in one column, and an image in the other
- I Submit

One of two things happens:

- If the image column is required, the submit fails, and I am told "The [column name] column is required." The column is empty, as if I never added an image.
- If the image column is NOT required, the submit is successful, but when I go back to edit the entry, that image is missing.

In the database, the image column for the Matrix row is blank (as opposed to NULL), but the rest of the row looks right.

If I edit an existing entry, I have no issues with the existing images saving and persisting - they are not deleted - but new rows that I create on an existing entry have the same issue (images that are added don't get saved to the DB). Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is the answer I just added here any help? http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/15290/150

Comment: Nope. It looks like it might be an issue with the now 2-days-old version of Matrix - I reverted to 2.5.6 and it resolved the problem.

Comment: Matrix 2.5.10 fixes this.