# Matrix does not save rows above 165

Tags: matrix

My matrix does not save its data anymore.

I use matrix for a table of persons that hold a certain certificate. four textfields and one date field. I want to add 300 people, but I am at row 165 now, and matrix won't save the last name of this person, so right in the middle of a row, on a regular text field, nothing more can be saved. The save seems to go through, but when you click 'edit this entry' the newly entered data is gone.

Another strange thing is the date field now uses another data format to display the date; suddenly the times have an AM/PM notation where before they used the 24h clock. But the issue is not limited to the d

Data entry was handled by the client and they have twice entered all 300 names by hand - only to find them lost them when reopening the entry. The site needs to go live, but I cannot get all the data in the field…

System setup:

- EE 2.7.2
- Matrix 2.5.10
- mysql 4.1.6
- php 5.4.4

Answer (score 1):

This is usually caused by the PHP Suhosin patch limiting the number of POST variables which may be submitted on a single page.

See: https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/15290/150

Comment: Also, the date display format is controlled by the user's time format preference in localization settings.

Comment: Only 2 weeks ago i had to create a channel for these matrix entries because of the same issue.